# Disable network connection

Tags: java

How could I temporarily disable a network connection in Java?

Comment: Yep, I agree with Mitch...  the easiest way you're going to find is to just pull the cable, or disable the network adapter

Answer (score 4):

A fairly complicated but feasible way to do this is to create a custom socket implementation factory. You can register it by calling [`Socket.setSocketImplFactory()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSocketImplFactory%28java.net.SocketImplFactory%29).

Your custom factory will then have to return custom socket implementations that simply throw an `IOException` at every connection attempt.

Note that this only stops outgoing connections, if you want to stop your application accepting incoming connections as well, you'll have to play a similar trick on `ServerSocket`s.

Comment: I have implemented a library for fault tolerance testing using this approach with SocketImplFactory - indeed it is feasible! http://stackoverflow.com/a/43056981/504452

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, disabling a network connection is OS-specific and I'm not aware of any standard Java APIs for accessing those OS features.  You'd probably have to do some OS-specific coding, e.g. via JNI or executing external programs, for each OS you intend to support.  The Java program would also need to be invoked with the proper privileges to be allowed to mess with the network interfaces.

Comment: sums up to the need of a OS-specific privileged service with access by secured/authenticated interface

Answer (score 2):

Would these work?
On windows:

```
Runtime.getRuntime ().exec ("ipconfig/release");
```

On linux ( assuming the network interface is called eth0:

```
 Runtime.getRuntime ().exec ("ifconfig eth0 down");
```

Comment: i use this method on a application where i just release the connection for all wireless connection.And then renew it after my application is done.

I used this page as a reference:
http://compnetworking.about.com/od/workingwithipaddresses/a/ipconfig.htm

Comment: in the linux case, in preparation one needs to identify relevant adapters

Answer (score 2):

[Sniffy](http://sniffy.io/) allows you to [block outgoing network connections](http://sniffy.io/docs/latest/#_non_servlet_applications) in your Java applications - it will throw a `ConnectException` whenever you try to establish a new connection to restricted host.

Just add `-javaagent:sniffy.jar=5559` to your JVM arguments and point your browser to `localhost:5559` - it will open a web page with all discovered connections to downstream systems and controls to disable certain connections.

[image: Sniffy connections console]

If your application is web-based, you can even do it directly from your application opened in browser - see a demo here: http://demo.sniffy.io/owners?lastName=

Click on a widget in bottom-right corner, select `Network Connections` tab, disable and connection to `localhost:8967` (database) and reload a page to see it in action.

*Disclaimer: I'm the author of Sniffy*

Comment: Is there a way to block outgoing traffic for arbitrary Java code programatically with Sniffy? Say I have a Java proxy. Can I run it with sniffy and block the traffic at certain point in my code?

Comment: @AlexeyR. it is possible - you need either to attach the sniffy agent during proxy startup using -javaagent parameter or use Java Attach API in order to do it in runtime. After that you can use sniffy REST API to block the traffic

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming this is under Windows, Vista or later)

You can disable an interface via [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394595%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which can be accessed through a bridge such as [JACOB](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/).

Answer (score 0):

you can disable all interfaces using wmic path `win32_networkadapter` where `PhysicalAdapter = True` call disable